# Ionic 3 image not rendering on page

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

im trying to link an img to my ionic page, and even using local file it doesnt render, I tried uploading it via external URL, or even adding it to the same folder as my page, even then it doesnt render, it just occupies a grey area around it and i have no idea why, 
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzTCK.jpg
please help

```
    <ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Test</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-auto push-4>
        <h1>Bem Vindo</h1>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-img [width]="310" [height]="200" src="https://imgur.com/a/QrUpBaV"></ion-img>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <hr>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6 offset-4>
        <h2>Consultas</h2>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

  <div text-center>
    <ion-slides>
      <ion-slide>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, odio tempor periculis ex eum. Pro quem expetendis an, nam fierent deserunt ex. His simul voluptatum appellantur te, te vim cetero invenire, impedit incorrupte mea ea. Mea ei altera utroque, saepe ubique recteque ut sea, ne mel case option. Pro at consul constituto dissentiet, id amet sanctus constituto quo. Eos eu solet melius suscipiantur, in indoctum laboramus vix. Ne qui salutatus conclusionemque.

      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        Salutandi honestatis vituperatoribus an nam, mollis facilisi an pri. Nec te rebum admodum, dico natum solum duo ex. Ne enim vidisse sit. Ea dolores hendrerit eos. Ad vix definitionem necessitatibus, cu adipisci posidonium mel, ei cetero eleifend pri.

      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
        Vis eu dolore utamur, te vide eloquentiam mei. Iusto aliquando democritum cu sed. In duo adipisci salutatus. Has eu posse mediocrem argumentum, autem cetero aperiam eam ei, et exerci commune cum. Te mea dicit postulant, iusto albucius id vis.
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
  </div>

  <br>
  <button ion-button block color="custom-green" (click)="onEntrarLogin()">Entrar</button>
  <h6 (click)="onEntrarCadastro()"><u>Já possui cadastro? clique em entrar. Caso ainda não possua cadastro, clique aqui para se cadastrar!</u></h6>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: are you sure the image path is correct?

Comment: i mean, im referring an external link, unless im probably missing something, but as far as i believe it should work since im using an uploaded link, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the image path is incorrect, try:

```
<ion-img [width]="310" [height]="200" src="https://i.imgur.com/xVhNrnM.jpg"></ion-img>
```

Comment: your image url was wrong, you had to change https://imgur.com/a/QrUpBaV to https://i.imgur.com/xVhNrnM.jpg, because the link of image you provided was actually a page web with image in it not an image.

Comment: Nice, thanks for pointing it out, it was a basic mistake, i thought it was something to worry about, i will accept your answer in 5 minutes, it wont let me accept it right now lol, but thanks again!